# Is there a way to implement IPC to a HTML5 web browser (served using LAMP server)?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ipc, lamp

Forgive me if this is a silly question but I could really use advice on the direction to look at for a project I am working on.

I made a webserver that streams RTSP to a webpage using LAMP, php and mysql; and served a html template. This was done on a raspberry pi and it all works fine as is. Also done on an Ubuntu VM.
EXAMPLE I FOLLOWED: https://www.thewebblinders.in/programming/article/rtsp-streaming-on-a-web-browser-6069

The next part of my project was to add buttons to the html page, that when pressed send a universal protocol command. I found that I needed to do this using IPC (inter-process communication) however I'm not really sure how to implement this to what I have now.

**At the moment my system works simply as a html webpage that is served from /var/www/html using  npx http-server --cors (from the open source server environment NODE.js)**

I'm not really sure how I could implement a python or javascript back end that communicates to something like electron.js (I tried the latter method but had no success).

Would it be a separate program that acts as a server that hosts the html page instead of Node.js? Would I still keep my templates and methods in the LAMP src directory (/var/www/html)?

**Any advice on the possible direction I could look at would be a lot of help. I've not found much online that discusses IPC work on html templates served by node.js.** The only html related topic I've seen relating to it is JavaScript with electron.js and that changes the way my webserver is ran.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: There is really a lot of information missing. The simplest way to implement a button is to issue a GET or POST request to an HTTP server whenever a user clicks the button in his browser. What should the buttons be doing?

Comment: Hi, sorry if I have been brief. I'd like to send a string command, ideally using IPC, when the user presses the button. Can this be done using GET and POST requests?

Comment: IPC is just a general idea. Mainly on how to call a function in a different process, or even a different computer, and get back a result. There are literally thousands of ways on how to do that. POST'ing to a web server is the most obvious way in your case. Here is the absolute basic implementation: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I will look into that. The only reason I need to work within the constraints of IPC is because I will later be working with c++ modules that expect IPC input.

Comment: Again, IPC is just a concept. Especially in C++, there are literally hundreds of ways to do IPC.